# Dot dotdot dotdotdot as loading?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, loading

I wanna create some loading dots, like this:

At 0000 miliseconds the span content is: `.`

At 0100 miliseconds the span content is: `..`

At 0200 miliseconds the span content is: `...`

In a loop.

What is the best / easiest way to make it?

Comment: if you just add "." each 100ms to the span content, doesn't it work? span.innerHTML += ".";

Comment: I like this intuitive title.

Comment: Excellent title !!!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<span id="wait">.</span>

<script>
var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
    var wait = document.getElementById("wait");
    if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 3 ) 
        wait.innerHTML = "";
    else 
        wait.innerHTML += ".";
    }, 100);
</script>
```

---

Or you can get fancy and have them go forward and back:

```
<span id="wait">.</span>

<script>
    window.dotsGoingUp = true;
    var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
        var wait = document.getElementById("wait");
        if ( window.dotsGoingUp ) 
            wait.innerHTML += ".";
        else {
            wait.innerHTML = wait.innerHTML.substring(1, wait.innerHTML.length);
            if ( wait.innerHTML === "")
                window.dotsGoingUp = true;
        }
        if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 9 )
            window.dotsGoingUp = false;



        }, 100);
    </script>
```

Or you could make them go back and forth randomly:

```
<span id="wait">.</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
        var wait = document.getElementById("wait");
        if ( Math.random() < .7 )
            wait.innerHTML += ".";
        else
            wait.innerHTML = wait.innerHTML.substring(1, wait.innerHTML.length);
        }, 100);
</script>
```

Or I could get a life and stop posting additional snippets.... :D

As Ivo said in the comments, you need to [clear the interval](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-clearInterval.aspx) at some point, especially if you are not loading a new page after the waiting is finished. :D

Comment: Now what's the point of having the interval go on forever after it there are 3 dots? ;)

Comment: @Ivo: Errm... when there are three dots, it goes back to zero. And so on. For a loading animation or so.

Comment: @thejh Hm? ah... there's an update comment on the other answer, always love incomplete / mis-worded questions.

Comment: any way to use this in React app?

Comment: best way is with css, see next answer

Answer (score 59):

Or.. you can do it with CSS ;)

```
<p class="loading">Loading</p>

.loading:after {
  content: ' .';
  animation: dots 1s steps(5, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes dots {
  0%, 20% {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  40% {
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  60% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  80%, 100% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 white;}}
```

[Codepen sample](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/gbPaVx)

Comment: is that compatible with older browsers?

Comment: @BabuJames "What" is old? IE8 and such? No, sadly not! https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: How do you make it faster?

Comment: Really nice and clean way

Comment: @MoneceSolis change `1s` to `0.5s` to make it go faster

Comment: This was helpful. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 17):

Example: https://codepen.io/lukaszkups/pen/NQjeVN

You can animate css `content` too!

```css
p span:before {
    animation: dots 2s linear infinite;
    content: '';
  }

  @keyframes dots {
    0%, 20% {
      content: '.';
    }
    40% {
      content: '..';
    }
    60% {
      content: '...';
    }
    90%, 100% {
      content: '';
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Loading<span></span></p>
```

Comment: This is a simple & effective solution IMO.

Comment: thank you! I've even wrote a blog post about it :D https://lukaszkups.net/notes/lets-create-dot-dot-dot-dot-dot-dot-css-loading-animation/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 8):

This is similar to Veiko Jääger's solution.  With this solution, the color of the dots is the same as the text it associates with.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
.appendMovingDots:after {
    content: ' .';
    animation: dots 3s steps(1, end) infinite;
}
@keyframes dots {
    0%, 12.5% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    37.5% {
        text-shadow: .5em 0;
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: .5em 0, 1em 0;
    }
    62.5% {
        text-shadow: .5em 0, 1em 0, 1.5em 0;
    }
    75% {
        text-shadow: .5em 0, 1em 0, 1.5em 0, 2em 0;
    }
    87.5%, 100%{
        text-shadow: .5em 0, 1em 0, 1.5em 0, 2em 0, 2.5em;
    }
} 
  </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <span class="appendMovingDots" style="font-size:20px">This is a test</span> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/subTZ/

```
var span = document.getElementById('myspan');

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if ((span.innerHTML += '.').length == 4) 
        span.innerHTML = '';
    //clearInterval( int ); // at some point, clear the setInterval
}, 100);
```

Comment: Yeah, but that creates after some time ................................ a very long span. How can i clear that after 3 dots?

Comment: @Thew: Just test the `length` of the `innerHTML` each time, then use the `clearInterval` I included. I didn't know you only wanted 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 4):

```js
      
    
    let span = document.querySelector('span');
        i = 0;
    
    setInterval(() => {
        span.innerText = Array(i = i > 2 ? 0 : i + 1).fill('.').join('');
    }, 500)
```

```html
loading<span></span>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, the easiest way is an `if`/`else` statement.

However, a bit math to calculate the dots-length and the famous `Array.join`-*hack* to repeat the dot-char, should do the trick too.

```js
function dotdotdot(cursor, times, string) {
  return Array(times - Math.abs(cursor % (times * 2) - times) + 1).join(string);
}

var cursor = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = dotdotdot(cursor++, 3, '.')
}, 100);
```

You could improve the readability a bit, by wrapping the "count-up-and-down"-part and "string-repetition" in separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

With `String.prototype.repeat()` you can do:

```
var element = document.querySelector(...);
var counter = 0;

var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
    counter += 1
    element.innerHTML = '.'.repeat(1 + counter % 3)
}, 350);

// Use the following to clear the interval
window.clearInterval(intervalId)
```

Note: `String.prototype.repeat()` is currently not supported in < IE11