# jQuery loop and append crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So basically, I am attempting to display a Bootstrap Modal once a specific image is clicked. I am then attempting to display some text and image within a paragraph tag that will be changed every 600 milliseconds like so:

`Playing -> Playing. -> Playing.. -> Playing...`

Once the `text` becomes `'Playing...'`, it will return back to the start as `'Playing'`, and over and over again until the Modal's `display` class becomes `none`.

I am calling all this after a `setTimeOut` function since I need to wait for the Bootstrap Modal to load first to test against its class.

Although, my code is crashing the browser every time, and due to that, I cannot view the developer tools to find out the problem.

```
$(".tutorial").click(function () {
    $('#tutorialModal').modal('show');
    $(this).toggleClass('playingGif'); //display 'playing' background image
    $(this).toggleClass('tutorial'); //turn off regular background image

    setTimeout(function () {
        while ($('#tutorialModal').css('display') == 'block') {
            var text = 'Playing';

            $('p', this)
            .delay(600)
            .queue(function (n) {
                $(this).html(text);
                n();
            });

            if (text == 'Playing...') {
                text = 'Playing';
            } else {
                text += '.';
            }
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: @DamonSmith - Crashes in both Chrome and Firefox. Haven't tested in any others yet.

Comment: the reason why it's crashing is probably because it's in a busy loop, constantly queueing up functions to run, you probably think that because that delay is there, the while loop will take 600 millis per step but no.

Comment: `while ($('#tutorialModal').css('display') == 'block')` this is the culprit.

Comment: @undefined - Is there a better alternative to my approach?

Comment: [Have you checked other questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639716/dot-dotdot-dotdotdot-as-loading-in-js)

Comment: @undefined - You stated that it was the while loop that was the culprit, not the appending?

Comment: Actually both of them, while the condition is true you are appending and appending and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var text = 'Playing';
function startPlaying() {

  if($('#tutorialModal').css('display') == 'block') {


    $('p', this).html(text);
    n();

    if (text == 'Playing...') {
      text = 'Playing';
    } else {
      text += '.';
    }
    window.setTimeout(startPlaying, 500);
  }
}
startPlaying();
```

that way, it runs every 500 millis, it updates the playing... text and then if it's still displayed it will queue up another run of the function in another 500 millis. I didn't try out this code, it's just to give you a general idea.

Comment: Changed `startPlaying()` to `window.setTimeout(startPlaying, 500);` and removed `n();` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!